# velocity RHS of #set statement is null. why?

Tags: velocity

i'm using eclipse (spring+mybatis+maven+velocity)
mybatis mapper OK, Controller OK, view(tables.vm) OK
but console log is RHS of #set statement is null.

why is Velocity  [debug] RHS of #set statement is null. Context will not be modified. /WEB-INF/views/velocity/tables.vm[line 6, column 1]

controller code

```
@RequestMapping("/join")
public ModelAndView main(){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("velocity/tables");

    List list = userDaoImpl.getTables();
    System.out.println("list : " + list);
    mav.addObject("list",list);

    return mav;
}
```

userDaoImpl.getTables OK (get List)

tables.vm

```
<html>
<head>
<title>abc</title>
</head>

<body>

#set ($list = $parameter.list)
$list

<strong>body.<strong>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

That happens because the value you're trying to assign is indeed `null`.

If you really want to allow assigning `null` values to variables, and get rid of that log message, then you should change the `directive.set.null.allowed` setting in the Velocity configuration. But this doesn't solve the fact that the list is not found...

I'm not familiar with how Spring works, but are you sure the list should be stored under `$parameter`? Isn't it already under `$list`? Try printing `$list` in your template to check.